# Can C/C++ compiler optimise pass-by-value by pass-by-reference during compilation?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, compiler-optimization

In more high-level languages like Swift for example, the one of the most common and powerful compiler optimization is `copy-on-write` mechanism, which basically turns every pass-by-value to pass-by-reference until the value is actually required to change at which point the real copy is actually made.

Since C/C++ have explicit semantics for pointers, references, pass-by-value and pass-by-reference, does its compilers guarantee to respect those semantics exactly?

```
void FSlow(BigObject x) { /* only access BigObject, never modify */ }

void FFastRef(const BigObject& x) { /* only access BigObject, never modify * }

void FFastPointer(const BigObject* const x) { /* only access BigObject, never modify * }
```

I.e. could they effectively rewrite `FSlow` to be like `FFastRef`/`FFastPointer` if they decide it would not change the outcome?

I guess I'm interested in both what C and C++ standards say about it and how the actual compilers usually behave in practice if it's up to them by standards.

Comment: As long as the observed behavior is the expected, a compiler is allowed to do pretty much anything.

Comment: The C compiler may optimise code in any way it likes, provided the result's behaviour is indistinguishable from the original. It may remove a funtion entirely, or use a different library function, so Yes.

Comment: So no guarantees for sure. But I feel like in practice for this value/ref semantics change this is rarely the case since mechanics for assurance that behaviour would not change should be quite involved especially in multithreaded environment. So using explicit pass-by-reference should still be preferred as an optimization, the one should not rely on compiler for this one.

Comment: Compilers make crazy-nice optimizations under the hood all the time. One would have to look at the assembly code to realize what it did.

Comment: Copy-on-write is at best tricky in a multi-threaded application. Early on in C++ `std::string` could be implemented with copy-on-write internally; that was banned when C++ added thread support.

Comment: Does that `FSlow` function have external or internal linkage? Compilers are allowed to do whatever they see fit with functions with internal linkage, however they MUST respect platform ABI for functions with external linkage.

Comment: In C++ it is tricky when the BigObject copy/move construction has side effects. What compiler may or may not do was changed slightly in each of C++11, C++14 and C++17.  But if it does not have side effects then compiler can do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since C/C++ have explicit semantics for pointers, references, pass-by-value and pass-by-reference, does its compilers guarantee to respect those semantics exactly?

No.  Their specifications describe C and C++ behavior in terms of an abstract machine.  A certain, fairly few kinds of actions of the abstract machine are categorized as "observable behavior".  A conforming implementation can behave however it likes as long as the observable behavior produced matches what the abstract machine is specified to produce when running the same program with the same input.  This is the basic justification for pretty much all optimizations implemented by compilers.

In C, the observable behavior is

- `volatile` accesses to objects
- writes to files (as judged at program termination)
- the I/O semantics of interactive devices (mainly to do with buffering modes)

> I.e. could they effectively rewrite FSlow to be like FFastRef/FFastPointer if they decide it would not change the outcome?

They could, in principle, provided that they also determined that there could not be any calls to `FSlow()` that the compiler did not have the opportunity to adjust properly.  In practice, this is a fairly high bar to clear.  Separate compilation is a problem for making such determinations, and so are function pointers.

However, if `FSlow()` were comparatively small then a more common and likely optimization would be simply to inline it into calling functions where it was possible to do so (approximately the same places where it would be possible to adjust its calling convention).

> I guess I'm interested in both what C and C++ standards say about it and how the actual compilers usually behave in practice if it's up to them by standards.

The specs say very little about compiler ("translator") behavior.  They are written mostly in terms of the behavior that programs must exhibit.

Comment: Yup, separate compilation is the major obstacle for changing the calling convention.  I think some of the major compilers may do stuff for `static` functions, but IDK if they do this.  Options like `gcc -fwhole-program -O3 *.c`, or maybe some LTO options (perhaps combined with "hidden" visibility for symbols), can let compilers know that there can't be any other callers to a global function other than the ones it can see.  So that makes it possible in theory; whether any real compilers do is another matter.  Compilers that aim to be useful for systems programming tend to follow the ABI.

Comment: I know GCC will make `foo.clone.constprop123` versions of a function if it chooses not to inline but wants to specialize a function for one arg being a constant.  So it might still do something like this to make a by-ref version of a function while other (hypothetical) callers can still call the by-value version under the standard symbol name.  But that probably doesn't help across compilation units, unless you have LTO.

Answer (score 2):

No it cannot because:

- `FSlow` works on a copy of the object while `FFastRef` works on a reference to the object
- in C++ `const &` means that the object cannot be modified via this reference. However if the original object is mutable then the object can be modified from outside the function (i.e. from another thread). This forces `FFastREf` to always load the value from the original object at every access, while `FSlow` uses the copy.

Now there is something to say that unsynchronized access to the object (with at least one write) is Undefined Behaviour. I'm not 100% sure but I think that if the compiler can prove that the access to `BigObject` is unsynchronized inside the function then that would mean that it cannot be modified from outside the function so it could theoretically optimize the access to it in that case.

Comment: +1 That's a keen observation. This certainly seems to suggest that compilers can't do what the OP is asking without violating the language spec. Regarding if the compiler can detect whether the access is unsynchronized, that's surely impossible (without being overly strict). Synchronization can take many forms. Something obvious (though platform-dependent) would be a mutex. Something less obvious would be a mutex managed by an external party with locks acquired and released via a REST api, a transaction in a database, messaging through a pipe, execution of another program, etc.

Comment: So this seems not actually to be "no", but rather "the circumstances described cannot arise".  That is, the assertion is that a compiler is incapable of determining that the proposed transformation cannot affect the outcome.  Although I agree that a compiler cannot make such a determination in general, I don't think I accept that there cannot be any case where a compiler (correctly) makes such a determination.

Comment: So it basically seems that this particular optimisation is trivial (and thus would be kind of expectable) in a single-threaded environment, but it's close to impossible in multi-threaded environment? It's interesting if and how compilers try to detect those circumstances. But I guess it's not hard (especially in C++) to just use pass-by-reference whenever sensible, no reason to rely on complier in this case anyway + it makes intentions clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Optimizing it in gcc is only possible if the function is inlined. IMO if the function is not inlined and the object is immutable then it is missed optimization.

```
int __attribute__((always_inline)) foo(const int *restrict x, size_t y, size_t z)
{
    for(size_t attempt = 0; attempt < y; attempt++)
    {
        if(x[y] == rand()) return x[y];
    }
    return 0;
}

void bar(void)
{
    const int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%d", foo(arr,100,rand()%(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/o99d74oxT